# webdriver crash open window

Tags: javascript, crash, selenium-webdriver, tiling

I use [behave](https://github.com/behave) python lib to create a bdd test suite. I have following step implementation:

```
@given(u"open new window")
def step_impl(context):
    context.browser.execute_script("window.open()")
```

The problem is that in [Notion](http://notion.sourceforge.net/) tiling manager firefox webdriver crashes during attempt to open new window. No such problem in gnome.

If I run firefox as regular without behave — javascript's `window.open()` creates a new tab without crashing.

Please help. I don't want to abandon Notion.

Comment: I'm trying to find workaround with `switch_to_window`. By switching and closing a windows, but no luck yet.

Comment: I've managed to find workaround, but still I don't understand what happens. I can't get adequate `window.name`. When I inspect my page with webdriver's firefox I get unexpected window name, but it works. Although, the name that I inspect in regular browser for same page is different. About crashes: `switch_to_window` into the first page at the end of bdd scenario relieves of crashing, but some awkwardness remain. For instance, firebug's console is unusable.

Comment: Webdriver gets `window.name` from last key of server's response.

Comment: Hi! I maintain notion. If this crashes Firefox on Notion and not in other window managers I'd love to fix it, though I'm not familiar with `behave`. Can you provide a complete reproducible example?